# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: reactjs, npm

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
```

Я подключил react как описано https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/25.1.php
так же установил npm react.
что ещё требуется?

package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: package.json можно посмотреть? Есть мнение, что не подключен транспайлер и соответствующий `loader`в сборщике.

Comment: {
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.1.0"
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется все дело в транспиляторе кода,у вас используется синтаксис es6 который не поддерживается нативно, нужно использовать `babel`, он переводит код из es6 синтаксиса в es5

Ну или просто использовать es5 синтаксис:

```
var React = require('react');
```

[Посмотрите наглядно отличия](http://cheng.logdown.com/posts/2015/09/29/converting-es5-react-to-es6)

Comment: React.Core установлен, я так понимаю это и есть babel или как его использовать? https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation тут дикость какая-то

Comment: Вы используете какой-нибудь сборщик типо `Webpack` ?
Нет,это не то. Babel это просто транспилятор,который перегоняет код из es6/7 синтаксиса в es5.
Посмотрите ссылку которую я приложил выше,там наглядно показаны отличия стандартов. Если не можете разобраться с babel'ом, то просто используйте es5 синтаксис

Comment: [Смотрели это?](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation)